# How to download website when URL doesn't change after data addition

Tags: python, url, download

I would like to download data from http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/ site. Case is that when I enter data on it through program the URL doesn't change, so file saved on disc has a page same as the one which were opened from the begining without data.Maybe I don't know how to access this site after adding data? I'm new in Python and tried to look for solution but with no result so if there was such issue, please link me. Here's my code. I appreciate all responses:)

```
import requests
import selenium
import select as something
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import pdfkit

url = "http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/?locale=pl"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path ="C:\\Users\\Python\\Chromedriver.exe")


driver.get("http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/")
#wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
obj = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("countryCombobox"))
obj = obj.select_by_index(1)

vies_r = requests.get(url)
vies_vat = driver.find_element_by_id("number")
vies_vat.send_keys('U54799909')

vies_verify = driver.find_element_by_id("submit")
vies_verify.click()

path_wkhtmltopdf = r'C:\Users\Python\wkhtmltox\wkhtmltox\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe'
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_wkhtmltopdf)
print(driver.current_url)
pdfkit.from_url(driver.current_url, "out.pdf", configuration=config)
```

Ukalo

Comment: I don't see where you download page. You only use `path_wkhtmltopdf` to generate `pdf` but you can put different text in place `"out.pdf"` to save it with different name. Where is the problem ?

Comment: BTW: maybe you should use HTML instead url - `pdfkit.from_string(driver.page_source, ...)`

Comment: _Case is that when I enter data on it through program the URL doesn't change, so file saved on disc has a page same as the one which were opened from the begining without data.Maybe I don't know how to access this site after adding data?_ I'm not sure I understand, what do you mean? Can you clarify your question?

Comment: AMC case is that I access page and enter data(member state and VAT number) then click verify and page goes to response in which shows that number is valid. I want to download exactly this page with my data and answer that it is valid. I thought that pdfkit works this way (source,where to save, don't understand what configuration is for). Furas, your answer is good but is there a way to cut off all links from it? I've got what I want but there is a lot of hyperlinks before what I'm intersted in